# Extract property value from HTML like text corpse

Tags: nlp, nltk, etl

I have 200MB of articles taken from a newspaper.

The structure of this corpse of text is the following:

- Each article is wraped in a `<ext></ext>` tag
- The sentences of the article are inside `<p><s></s></p>` tags

Example of one article:

```
<ext id=12 cad="Caderno Especial" sec="nd" sem="94a">
<p>
<s> sentence.... </s>
...
<s> sentence.... </s>
</p>
<p>
<s> sentence.... </s>
...
<s> sentence.... </s>
</p>
</ext>
```

The pattern repeats, where the `id` property is unique for each article (ranging from 1 to 400000)

I would like to extracted the content of the `cad` property of each article. For example, for the above article it would be `Caderno Especial`. So, in the end, I'm going to create a SQL table with a single column, where each row indicates the value of `cad` for a given article. The table will have 400000 rows. How can I do that?

Comment: More details would be helpful. Is this XML? Or just XML-style tags? If it's the former, you should use an XML parser. If it's the latter, you can define a regular expression to quickly identify the `cad` field and extract its contents.

Comment: All the data is in a text file, with plain text. The extension of the file is ".0" (which I've never seen before, actually). I could open it with a notepad. So I think it's just  XML-style tags